python + SQLAlchemy: deleting taking 250,000x longer than querying the same data
I am accessing a PostGres database using python and SQL ALchemy. I can't figure out how to delete in a timely manner. The query is fast, the delete takes 250,000x longer
I have a table, 'RP', that has 92M rows. I am trying to delete some of them.
I have some code that finds the objects I want to delete that works and runs fast, it is basically:
import sqlalchemy as sa
...
with Session(engine, autobegin=True) as session:
...
    r_count = 0
    for image in images:
        sub_r = sa.select(RP).filter_by(d_id=image.id)
        count = session.execute(sa.select(sa.func.count()).select_from(sub_r)).scalar_one()
        r_count += count
    #print timing and count info here

This loop executes ~500 times in ~0.2 seconds, because len(images)~500, each time counting ~10-200 individual rows, for a total of ~70,000 rows that I want to delete.
When I add a delete command below, it takes much longer. Each of the 500 passes through the loop, which originally took <0.01 second to execute, now is taking 250 seconds for each iteration, meaning that it will take 36+ hours to delete these 70,000 rows (which were found by a query in <0.5 seconds).
import sqlalchemy as sa
...
with Session(engine, autobegin=True) as session:
...
    r_count = 0
    for image in images:
        sub_r = sa.select(RP).filter_by(d_id=image.id)
        count = session.execute(sa.select(sa.func.count()).select_from(sub_r)).scalar_one()
        r_count += count
    #print timing and count info here

#New Delete Code Below
    for image in images:
        session.query(RP).filter_by(d_id=image.id).delete()
        #session.commit()  #tried with this inserted and removed, doesn't seem to matter

        # Deleting using the session does not go faster
        # del_rp = sa.delete(RP).where(RP.d_id ==image.id)
        # session.execute(del_rp)

        # Deleting one at a time also doesn't seem to go faster
        # rois = session.query(RP).filter_by(d_id=image.id).all()
        # for r in rois:
        #     session.delete(r)

        #print timing for each loop here, ~260+ seconds for each loop

To summarize: I tried 3 main strategies. I tried doing session.query().filter_by().delete(), I tried doing session.execute(sa.delete().where()), and I tried doing a for loop on session.query().filter_by().all(), and then doing a session.delete(one). I also tried including session.commit() at points in the middle.
I am expecting it to execute much faster. I see no reason why the query should go fast and the delete take many orders of magnitude longer.
I am the only user on the server. So there is no other possible bottleneck besides this code. The commented out methods also seem to take many hundreds of seconds for a few dozen deletes (it would take me longer to gather precise timing info)
I am using the pgAdmin dashboard, and in the 'Tuples Out' view, I see ~200-300 seconds of flatline, then 4,000 fetched, 12 billion returned. If I'm deleting ~140 objects in that pass through the loop, then that corresponds to each individual delete causing a fetch/return of the whole 92M table. Is there some way to tell the delete that I don't care for any return value (assuming that's what is happening?)
I suppose I could try to be more clever and accumulate all 70,000 rows and issue a single delete command, but based on the pgAdmin dashboard, it seems like this will not help, because it seems like the session.query().filter_by().delete() is getting broken up individually anyways.
What am I supposed to be doing differently? I have tried .delete(synchronize_session='fetch'), it doesn't seem to help, but I don't remember if I tried it in every permutation.
Maybe this should be a second question, but I also can't figure out a way to interrupt the code. It seems like if I send a ctrl+C, it waits until the ~250 second loop iteration is done. If I use the pgAdmin tool, I don't have permission to kill the session. I don't want a bunch of idle threads clogging up the server, so at this point I'm just being patient and waiting for the loop
Edit: I checked the server as suggested. I see that the actual code being executed is
DELETE FROM rp WHERE rp.d_id = 5254591 RETURNING rp.id

That should just be returning a single ID, correct?
If I change my code to:
session.execute(sa.delete(RP).where(RP.d_id==image.id))
then the server log just says
DELETE FROM rp WHERE rp.d_id = 5254591 

But even with the modified, non-returning syntax, the pgAdmin dashboard is still saying that I'm executing dozens of queries and returning billions of tuples in <5 seconds, then 250+ seconds of the database doing nothing. My code is being executed on the server and connecting via loopback IP, should be no network latency.

Check your logs to see what SQL statements are actually being executed. I'm guessing you're making 70,000 queries. It could probably be done as one, or a few dozen.

Why can’t you delete all 70k records using a single query?

The first pass through the loop doing 500 search only session.execute() calls in 0.2 seconds total for all 500. The second time through, each session.query is taking 200+ seconds to execute. Why is it so much longer?

I'm not seeing a RETURNING clause in my DELETE statements. What version of SQLAlchemy are you using? What DBAPI driver (psycopg2?, psycopg(3)?, pg8000? …?)

@GordThompson I didn't set up this server, how can I tell what DBAPI driver I'm using? With respect to the RETURNING clause, see my edits above at the end of the original question.

If your SQLA connection URL starts with a drivername. postgresql:// defaults to psycopg2, otherwise it will be postgresql+psycopg://, postgresql+pg8000://, or whatever.

About the 12 billion returned pgAdmin is probably showing pg_stat_database.tup_returned which is not a number of tuples returned to the client, but a total count of tuples "returned from the disk" (i.e. read). You may ignore that metric for your problem.

Slow deletes like in your question are often due to foreign key constraints that are not supported by indexes. Try this query on your db to list the tables that lack indexes on FK contraints.

There's two potential performance issues.
Is d_id indexed?
First, if d_id is not indexed then the query will have to scan the whole table for each delete. This will get very, very slow. Make sure d_id is indexed.
Do it in one query.
Right now you're doing one query for each image. You can instead do it in a few bulk deletes.
Let's say you had to delete IDs 1, 2, 5, 8, 9, and 10. You're doing the equivalent of this.
delete from some table where d_id = 1;
delete from some table where d_id = 2;
delete from some table where d_id = 5;
delete from some table where d_id = 8;
delete from some table where d_id = 9;
delete from some table where d_id = 10;

Doing them all in one bulk query is much more efficient.
delete from some_table where d_id in (1, 2, 5, 8, 9, 10);

If the IDs span a large portion of the table, it might not even matter of d_id is indexed; it could be more efficient to scan the whole table once than to look up each d_id in the index.

That's the pure SQL explanation. I don't know SQLAlchemy well, but it would be something like this.
session.query(RP).filter(RP.id.in_(image_ids)).delete()

Doing all 70,000 at once might lock the table. You can try breaking it up into batches of about 1000.
# Or use itertools.batched in Python 3.12
from itertools import islice
def batched(iterable, n):
    # batched('ABCDEFG', 3) → ABC DEF G
    if n < 1:
        raise ValueError('n must be at least one')
    iterator = iter(iterable)
    while batch := tuple(islice(iterator, n)):
        yield batch

image_ids = list(map(id, images))
for batch in batched(image_ids, 1000):
    session.query(RP).filter(RP.id.in_(image_ids)).delete()

Something like that.

I think this is what I am doing, right? I'm not clear what the syntax difference is.
In the code above, the uncommented line is:
session.query(RP).filter_by(d_id=image.id).delete()
What's the difference between .filter and .filter_by?
That 'in' removes the for loop. That for loop should execute ~500 times (I clarified above). Each time through, it's chunking about 200 images, which is not all that different from the 1000 that you're suggesting.
The main problem is that statement to delete 200 images is taking 200+ seconds. It's not clear to me why it takes so long.

@JeffEllen re: "I think this is what I am doing, right?" - No, your code is issuing 500 DML statements similar to DELETE FROM rp WHERE rp.d_id = 5254591. Schwern is suggesting that instead of just counting the rows to be deleted, you make a list of the PK values in the "rp" table that need to be deleted and then issue one or more statements (depending on the batch size) like DELETE FROM rp WHERE rp.id IN (1234, 1235, …)

@GordThompson can you please exactly explain how to do that without writing the PostgreSQL string directly? The answer from @schwern has no delete in it. The code I provided session.query(RP).filter_by(d_id=image.id) matches ~200 rows each time through the loop, and I call .delete() on the whole ~200. I am not sure why that 1 line of my python code got issued as 200 individual PostgreSQL commands. This is only the start, I want to do more complex things later, so I don't want to manually create the PostgreSQL string, I'd like to better understand SQL Alchemy.

Maybe this is a related issue: According to the pgAdmin dashboard, DELETE FROM rp WHERE rp.d_id = 5254591 is taking 250+ seconds to delete 200 rows from a 92 million row table. Why? It only took .001 second to find those rows, so it's not my server specs. The 'tuples in' shows ~100-200 deletes every 250+ seconds, with lots of idle inbetween. The 'Tuples Out' Spikes to ~100-200 fetches and 12 Billion returned, but that spike is during a single 5 second tick on the graph. Then there's 250+ seconds of flatline on the graph. I'm executing the python on the server, no network latency.

@JeffEllen - If you run a query like DELETE FROM rp WHERE rp.d_id = 5254591 in pgAdmin does it say something like "DELETE 200 - Query returned successfully in 248 secs 57 msec."?

Also someone asked a similar question the other day and if there is not index on the d_id column it might be taking a long time to find the record but also if you have a lot of indexed columns they might need to be recomputed after the deletion.  @JeffEllen maybe post your table schema.

@JeffEllen - Further to Ian's comment, you might also check for child tables that have a foreign key pointing to your "rp" table. You can use a query like this (adjusting the values in the WHERE clause as required).

@JeffEllen Sorry about the incomplete code, I don't know SQLAlchemy well. I've expanded the answer to better explain what's happening in SQL (remember, SQLAlchemy is just issuing SQL commands) and to provide what I think is the correct SQLAlchemy.
